# ListActivity ormlite problem?

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a rather large amount of code written when I decided to use
ORMLite.

After reading the doc I found that I would need to extend like:

```
MyClass extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper>
```

but I have already extended it with ListActivity.

Is is possible to do it without extending OrmLiteBaseActivity?

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a requirement to extend `OrmLiteBaseActivity`.  You'll just need to manage more of the utility functions yourself.

Your best option would be to create your own `DatabaseHelper` inside your activity and to manage how many users there are of it and to discard it when it is done being used.  Generally speaking, this is the utility that the `OrmLiteBaseActivity` gives to you.  A mechanism which will manage your database objects for you.  It's just a convenience.

---

Example:

```
private static Dao<Agent, Object> agentDao = null;
public void someMethod() {
    if(agentDao == null){
      helper = (MyDBHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getContext());
      try {
        agentDao = helper.getAgentDao();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

I had implemented a method to return my DAOs on the class MyDBHelper.  Take a look at the [ORMLite Android Javadoc](http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/javadoc/ormlite-android/) as well as the more general [ORMLite Core Javadoc](http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/javadoc/ormlite-core/).  There are lots of good examples out there.

Comment: Tnx for help. Are there any examples of this. I am still new in this and some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[ @Nick's answer is fine but I thought I'd add more information. ]

ORMLite is missing a `OrmLiteBaseListActivity` class that was added in version 4.10 -- sorry about the miss.  In the meantime, you can easily create your own version of this class by copying the `OrmLiteBaseTabActivity` class changing the class that it extends from `TabActivity` to `ListActivity`.  Then change all of your list activity classes to extend this new class.  Once 4.10 is out then you can go back and remove the class.

For example:

```
public abstract class OrmLiteBaseListActivity<H extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper>
    extends ListActivity {
    // insert contents of the OrmLiteBaseTabActivity class here
}
```